# Line count with top command

Tags: bash, grep, wc

I need to find the number of processes that are running with a command name that matches a specific pattern. And I need to check for the number of processes on regular intervals.

I am grepping the output of the top command with the command pattern and attempting to find the number of processes every time.

The following will (for example) grep the all the processes that matches the command pattern and print it out dynamically.

```
top -bcd 1 | grep worker | grep apache
```

Now instead of the list, I just need the count of processes to print out dynamically.
I tried the following that wont work for me.

```
top -bcd 1 | grep worker | grep apache | wc -l
```

and

```
top -bcd 1 | grep worker | grep -c apache
```

If there is a completely different and better way to do it, please let me know that as well.

Comment: I would suggest using `watch pgrep apache`.

Comment: @TomFenech, the thing is I need to write the output to a log file. I was hoping if I get the line count from above commands, I can just write it to a file, I'm not sure if this is possible with watch.

Comment: The timing won't be perfect but you could just go for a `while` loop with `sleep`: `while true; do pgrep apache | wc -l >> logfile; done`

Comment: @TomFenech, this works for me. Thanks. But I still wonder if there is a way to find the lines in a dynamic output like from top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the original problem in your question, i.e. checking the number of processes with a name matching a given pattern, I would suggest using `pgrep` with `watch`:

```
watch pgrep apache
```

You should be able to output this directly to a log file using a standard redirection `> out`. If that doesn't work, you could always roll your own loop to do something similar:

```
while true; do
    pgrep apache
    sleep 2
done > out
```

Answer (score 1):

Should you not have `pgrep`, there are always ways to produce this result with POSIX tools on linux.

```
while true; do
  awk '$0~"^"re{a++};END{print a}' re=apache /proc/[0-9]*/cmdline
  sleep 2
done
```